# Highlight individual observation in density and violin plot in R/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to highlight the position of an individual in a density plot and in a violin plot.

For instance, in the plot generated by the code bellow, I would like highlight "Mazda RX4" in the mtcars dataset. This could be by adding a point or bar to the value of that individual observation in each category

```
#density plot
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=drat))+
  geom_density() + facet_grid(cyl ~ .)

#violin plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),y=drat, fill=factor(am)))+
  geom_violin()
```

EDIT:
1) Based on @DatamineR answer bellow I as able to add the desired point (code bellow) to the violin plot.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),y=drat, fill=factor(am)))+ 
  geom_violin() + geom_point(data = mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4",])
```

However, the same +geom_point() did not work with the density plot. How can I add a point for that observation for the density plot?

2) Also, is it possible to use another marker, like a line segment or bar (perpendicular to the base line of the distribution) instead of a point?

Comment: Try `geom_point(data = mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4",])`

Comment: @DatamineR: tks, your suggestion works for the example given. But it does not work on my actual data. I get error "**Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'dist_fronteira' not found**" . If I don´t figure it out I'll edit the question posting the true dataset

Comment: It now works on my data also for the violin plot. Still don't know how to add the individual marker to the density plot.

Comment: Do you mean a different plot?

Comment: Yes (edited the question). Using your suggestion, I got the violin plot to work. I now wanted to replicate a similar chart but using density instead of violin plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for the first part of the question (add to your ggplot-code):

```
geom_point(data = mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4",])
```

[image]

For the second part of the question you can try(add to your ggplot-code):

```
geom_point(data = mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4",], aes(y = 0))
```

[image]